# Orientation change causes position center div to shift (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript

I'm using bootstrap and have used the vh code to vertically align a div. However, when the orientation changes, it causes the once vertically centered div to misposition, hence I tried writing some jquery to reload the window that will cause it to be centered once again. But the java is not working. So will be great if someone could point out to me, why it's not. Thanks.

CSS:

```
.vertical-align {
    height:auto;
    min-height: 100vh;

    /* Make it a flex container */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 

    /* Align the bootstrap's container vertically */
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-align-items : center;
    -moz-box-align : center;
    -ms-flex-align : center;
    align-items : center;

    -webkit-box-pack : center;
    -moz-box-pack : center;
    -ms-flex-pack : center;
    -webkit-justify-content : center;
    justify-content : center;

    flex-direction: row;

    width:100%;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    var wasPortrait = -1;
    var checkOrientation = function() {
        var isPortrait = (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth);
        if( isPortrait === wasPortrait ) { return; // Nothing to do here }
        wasPortrait = isPortrait;
        alert("change dected");
        location.reload();
    };
window.addEventListener( 'orientationchange', checkOrientation, false );
```

Comment: That isn't `jQuery`!! That's pure `javascript`!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'is not working'? Are you getting any errors? Is the `alert` firing? Also have you tried using the resize event rather than orientationchange? From what I recall not all devices report orientationchange.

Comment: a better question is why are you having to use javascript when you can use css media queries? [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en#apply-media-queries-based-on-viewport-size), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/orientation)

Comment: @Jared the alert is not firing. can't seem to figure what's wrong with my code